# How to pass an argument-required function without specifying argument to a child component in React Native

Tags: reactjs, function, react-native

I'm trying to make a components that requires a few props, where one of the props is receiving a function. All of the props are receiving the same data (argument for the function prop). Below is a code snippet to illustrate it:

```
<someComponent text={'Yes'}
               handler={() => someFunction('Yes')}
               anotherProps={"Yes"}
               yetAnotherProps={"Yes"} />
```

The problem is I feel that this implementation is too cumbersome -- if I want to re-use the component for another case, I need to change the 'Yes' inside all the props.

So I wanted to get rid of that, by passing a prop that take in the data and circulate that data among the rest of operation within the component. However the function is still needed to be passed into the props because the function involves setState in the parent component. Like this:

```
<someComponent data={'Yes'}
               handler={() => someFunction()}/>
```

Let's say the component I'm making is a button. The code inside the component:

```
return (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.handler(this.props.data)
                          style={this.props.data === 'Yes'? styles.chosen : styles.normal>
            <Text>{this.props.data}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
)
```

Problem arises because I did not pass any data into the function, so the setState failed. What is the correct syntax to properly pass just the function without specifying arguments into child component?

Answer (score 0):

You need have an parameter in handle like this:

```
<someComponent text={'Yes'}
               handler={(data) => someFunction(data)}
               anotherProps={"Yes"}
               yetAnotherProps={"Yes"} />
```